Django - Downloading someone's images with an API
Hello i am developing a blog project in django.
For each post there are images attached to it
I want to share my project with some friends ( by them cloning the github repo ), but don't want them to download all the images.
So i have made a new app on my project, an API with django-rest-framework that allow them to get the list of the images from my project
Once someone get the list, it create new instances of Post and ImagePost in the DB, based on the json value
They get the new instance in their DB, but they don't get the images, they only get the filepath
I have no idea how to give them the images using the API, and make the images goes into their project.
Thank you
So for my models:
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(ImagePost, related_name='images', blank=True)

class ImagePost(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_posts/', blank=True)

And my API classes :
class PostList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(archived=False)
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

class ImagePostList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = ImagePost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImagePostSerializer

class ImagePostSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ImagePost
        fields = ["id", "image" ]

The urls :
    path('post/list/', views.PostList.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    path('imagepost/list/', views.ImagePostList.as_view(), name='imagepost_list'),

And my function that create instances based on the json value:
def create_imagepost_from_url_json(request):

    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    domain = current_site.domain,
    url = "http://" + str(domain[0])+"/api/video/list/"

    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()

        for obj in data:
            ImagePost.objects.create(**obj)
    
    return redirect('index')


I suggest you update your ImagePostSerializer to include image data itself, and not just the file path. Ensure that all your imports for your serialization from rest_framework are imported before adding the below functionality.
Here is the modification of your code;

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import ImagePost

class ImagePostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True) # This will definitely include the image URL in the response for your friends

    class Meta:
        model = ImagePost
        fields = ["id", "image"]

NB: Ensure that Pillow is installed in your project, and if you are still developing locally, kindly add this code below on your project url.py for Django to serve your static files effortlessly.

from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Goodluck mate

Thanks for your quick response, I looked at ImageField but it didn't make any changes. I'm a bit confused, and i don't really understand where my problem came from. I'm now thinking of a CreateAPI inherited class to use, but I'm straying from my original goal

Hi there, where you able to figure it out, I mean getting the answer that you need?
